Overloading Interface methods with Callback Arguments
I have an interface in my project that takes in text in ByteArray form. It looks something like this
interface TextInputListener {

  
    fun onPinRequested(callback: (text: ByteArray) -> Unit)
}

I want to also be able to take in text in the form of Charsequence. My thinking now is to overload the method in the interface and provide default implementation for the new method. It will look something like this,
interface TextInputListener {

  
    fun onPinRequested(callback: (pin: ByteArray) -> Unit)
    
    fun onPinRequested(callback: (pin: Charsequence) -> Unit) = {
      // invoke byte Array onpinRequested with pin charsequence converted to byte array
    }

}

The issue here is two fold, I am not sure overloading is the right approach as it may have consequences for how the Listener is implemented in classes that use it. The second issue is that I do not know how add the syntax to transform the charsequence value in the callback argument for the new method into a bytearray that will be used in a callback to invoke the old method. How do I go about this?

The basic setup doesn’t make sense to me. The interface is a listener that when triggered receives other listener functions. What is it supposed to do with these listeners? Seems convoluted. Maybe you can describe an example of how this would be used—what class will be requesting instances of this listener, and what kind of class produces them and then reacts to returned listeners.
